# Display the google map Icons in different colours in MVC 5 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone tell me the Google map generated Java Script or C# code for dynamically located items 
for different category levels display the Google map Icons in different colours.

This my controller return value  var map = db.Locations.ToList();  View(map). This database table has around 100 record, what I need  for example category name AAA has record 12, BBB has 10, etc.. each category items need to display the Google map icons in different colours. I have attached my code.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> CourierList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var couriers = db.Locations.Select(x => x.CouriersName).Distinct().ToList();
        ViewBag.CourierList = new SelectList(couriers);
        var map = db.Locations.ToList();


        return View(map);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add icons on the list while pulling from database, if you are on STORED PROC using

```
WHEN Category = 'AAA' THEN 'red.ico' END
```

or can pull catergory in javascript and accordingly check it

```
var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CourierList));
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++) {
        var model = list[i];
        addMarker(model.IconUrl, new google.maps.LatLng(model.Latitude, model.Longitude));
        --addMarker(returnIcon(model.Category), new google.maps.LatLng(model.Latitude, model.Longitude)); for category
        }

    function addMarker(iconUrl, myLatLng) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            icon: iconUrl,
            map: map
        });
    }

    function returnIcon(category){
        var iconUrl = 'default.ico';
        if(category == 'AAA')
            iconUrl = 'abc.ico';
        if(category == 'BBB')
            iconUrl = 'red.ico';
        return iconUrl;
    }
```

Comment: if(category == 'AAA') 'AAA' without hard code value how do I modify this code dynamically because most of time I update database values.

Comment: its on comment
addMarker(returnIcon(model.Category), new google.maps.LatLng(model.Latitude, model.Longitude)); for category

Comment: I have added new link for google map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440324/google-map-icons-in-different-colours-java-script-my-code-is-not-working